# Javascript quiz result calculation/generation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a javascript quiz for my rails app in which there was a choice between only two answers for each question, I'm now trying to scale it up so that there are four questions and four results pages, but haven't been able to get it working so far. Can anybody help? I've tried changing the var calculations but haven't been successful so far.

```
function generateResult(answers) {
  var panda = bear = 0;
  for(var i =0; i < answers.length; i++){
    if(answers[i] == 1){
      bear++;
    }
    else {
      panda++;
    }
  }
    if(bear > panda) {
      return "sbear.html";
    }
    else if(bear > elephant) {
      return "sbear.html";
      }
     else if(bear > alpacha) {
      return "sbear.html";
      }

    else if(panda > bear) {
      return "sbear.html";
    }
    else if(panda > elephant) {
      return "sbear.html";
      }
     else if(panda > alpacha) {
      return "rpanda.html";
      }

     else if(alpacha > bear) {
      return "sbear.html";
    }
    else if(alpacha > panda) {
      return "sbear.html";
      }
     else if(alpacha > elephant) {
      return "alpach.html";
      }

    else {
      return "eleph.html"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the initialization of `elephant` and `alpacha` (alpaca?)?

Comment: I currently don't have it anymore, what I had for it previously didn't work and I'm unsure how to proceed

Comment: @Djangert Well then you need to define them. You can't expect code to work with undeclared variables.

Comment: Where did you initialize elephant and alpacha?

Comment: I know that, where I had defined them, provided me with problems. I was asking for help.

Comment: @Djangert, you didn't define them. You only used them and for sure, it populates error. You can't use any variable before defining that

Comment: Your question cannot be answered. Your example is incomplete and not explained. How are we supposed to know what your code is supposed to correctly do if we you don't tell us? Also as I already stated, the use of undeclared variables will result in an error. As in it needs to be fixed, it's not some optional unimportant thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure these are the right values of bear/panda/elephant/alpac(h)a, but you can swap those in pretty easy.

```
function generateResult(answers) {
   // initialize ALL variables
   var panda = bear = elephant = alpacha = 0;
   for(var i =0; i < answers.length; i++){
      if(answers[i] == 1){ // assuming bear == 1
         bear++;
      }
      else if(answers[i] == 2) { // assuming panda == 2
         panda++;
      }
      else if(answers[i] == 3) { // assuming elephant == 3
         elephant++;
      }
      else { // assuming alpacha == 4
         alpacha++;
      }
   }
   if (bear > alpacha && bear > panda && bear > elephant) {
      return "sbear.html";
   }
   else if (alpacha > bear && alpacha > panda && alpacha > elephant) {
      return "alpach.html";
   }
   else if (panda > alpacha && panda > bear && panda > elephant) {
      return "rpanda.html";
   }
   else {
      return "eleph.html";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer. I worked for my supposed list of answers

```
var answers = [1,2,3,4,2,2,2,3,4]
function generateResult(answers) {
    var animals = {
      1: 'bear',
      2: 'panda',
      3: 'elephant',
      4: 'alpacha'
    }

    var counts = [0,0,0,0];

    answers.forEach(function(answer){
      counts[answer-1]++;
    });

    return animals[counts.indexOf(Math.max(...counts))+1] + '.html';
}
```

Result:

> genarateResult(answers); // 'panda.html'